# Generate random, non overlapping image locations using Matlab

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, random, display

I have a specific problem I hope you will help me with. I am running an experiment using eyetracking. In each trial (84 trials in total) I have to present 50 images, 100x100 pixels each, 50 on the right side of the screen, 50 on the left, simultaneously.

I am trying to generate a random vector of coordinates of X and Y which adheres the following conditions:

Each randomly generated X and Y location coordinate pair must be equidistant by 50 pixels from the next. This means that all the images displayed on screen, all 50 of them, must have at least 50 pixels distance from each other. So if on of the image location pairs is x = 1 and y = 1, the other x and y pairs must not have a value within x + 100(image pixel number) + 50 (distance between images) = 151, and y + 100(image pixel number) + 50 (distance between images) = 151. Each trial must have coordinate/location x and y numbers for 50 images that adhere to these rules.

I am sorry this is so wordy. Can anyone please help?

All the best and thanks,
Dritan

Comment: you do realise you need a screen that has a resolution of at least `7500x15000` pixels, right?

Comment: Hi, yes of course, I understand that :). I also have a bigger screen than that :).

Answer (score 0):

One of the possibilities is to generate random locations and check if they are allowed. If not, just try a new location.

```
% configuration options
imageSize = 100;
margin = 50;
nImages = 50;
nTrials = 1000; % number of times to find a valid location before aborting

screen = zeros(2000, 2000); % screen on which to place the images

locations = zeros(nImages, 2)

for i=1:nImages % loop over all images
  for j=1:nTrials % try nTrials times at most
    % generate new random location
    x = randi(size(screen, 1) - imageSize + 1);
    y = randi(size(screen, 2) - imageSize + 1);

    % check if the location is allowed
    if checkIfAllowed(x, y, screen, imageSize, margin)
      % put the image on the screen
      screen(x + (0:imageSize-1), y + (0:imageSize-1)) = ones(imageSize);
      locations(i, :) = [x y];
      break; % break the inner for loop
    end
  end
  if j == nTrials % abort the process as no valid location is found
    warning('Failed to place all the images')
    break;
  end
end

imshow(screen) % show the images

% checks if an images may be placed at (x, y)
function allowed = checkIfAllowed(x, y, screen, imageSize, margin)
  range = -margin:imageSize+margin-1;
  xs = x+range;
  ys = y+range;
  xs = xs(xs > 1 & xs < size(screen, 1));
  ys = ys(ys > 1 & ys < size(screen, 1));
  allowed = all(screen(xs, ys) == 0);
end
```

The output is (note that the images are represented by white squares):

`locations` is a matrix with two columns (`x, y` image coordinate) and one row for each image.

[image]

**Discussion**

The disadvantage of this method is that it may take some time to find a valid location when space is scarce.

Comment: Can I get from here the x and y coordinates for all 50 images for each trial? I should end up with a matrix 84x100. In each row the x,y,x,y....xn, yn - coordinates for each of the 50 picture set to be displayed?

Comment: I added a matrix `locations`, which stores the output as 50x2. I think you will be able to adapt this to your needs.

Comment: An easier way is do{x1=rand(),y1=rand();x2=rand()y2=rand()}while(!allowed());

Comment: @MalcolmMcLean Matlab doesn't have a do-while loop (as far as I know) and it wouldn't make it much easier if you would ensure that the program will finish (after some trials), which is a good idea I think.

Comment: Hi guys, can I ask, does this code ensure i get the coordinates equally for left and right side if the screen for each trial i present the images? It is important for later statistical comparisons. Sorry to bother you.